# Django : Authenticate user login return none

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to create login form. In login.html when user type name and password, then it become user object. If there is return than it should redirect to loggedin.html and if else it should redirect to invaild.html. However it keeps return none.

This is my setting.py

```
#Authentication backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

#added for login authentification
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

urls.py

```
#user auth url
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'forum/login.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^auth/$', views.auth_view, name='auth'),
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'template_name': 'forum/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
url(r'^loggedin/$', views.loggedin, name='loggedin'),
```

Model.py

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import context
from django.template.context_processors import request, csrf

from forum.models import Article


def login(request):
   c = {}
   c.update(csrf(request))
   return render(request, 'forum/login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
   name = request.POST.get('name', '')
   password = request.POST.get('password', '')
   user = auth.authenticate(username=name, password=password)
   print(user)
   if user is not None:
       auth.login(request, user)
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin.html')
   else:
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid.html')

 def base(request):
   return render(request, 'forum/base.html', context)

 def loggedin(request):
   return render(request, 'forum/loggedin.html', {'name': request.user.name})

 def logout(request):
   return render(request, 'forum/logout.html')
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% if from.errors %}
not valid name or password
{% endif %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<form action="{% url 'forum:auth' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
 name
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
 password
 <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value=""/>
 <input type="submit" value="login"/>
 </form>
 {% endblock %}
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Any particular reason to be creating your own authentication system and not using Django auth app?

Comment: @GustavoReyes I just followed tutorial. I thought that it is Django auth app.

Comment: Django has built-in authentication,  you don't have to build it yourself. Take a look at this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html)